# Multilabel random forrest SKlearn class_weight ValueError: class_weight must be dict, 'balanced', or None

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, multilabel-classification

I am trying to use class_weight for the [sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)
for a multilabel problem. I have five unique labels [label1, label2, label3, label4, label5] and each label can be 1 or 0. Furthermore, each instance can have one or many labels, e.g., [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]. The amount of instances per class is imbalanced, hence I am trying to account for this by using class_weight argument. According to the documentation a list of dicts should be passed if the problem is multilabel.

> class_weightdict, list of dict or “balanced”, default=None
> Weights associated with classes in the form {class_label: weight}. If None, all classes are supposed to have weight one. For multi-output problems, a list of dicts can be provided in the same order as the columns of y.
> **Note that for multioutput (including multilabel) weights should be defined for each class of every column in its own dict. For example, for four-class multilabel classification weights should be [{0: 1, 1: 1}, {0: 1, 1: 5}, {0: 1, 1: 1}, {0: 1, 1: 1}] instead of [{1:1}, {2:5}, {3:1}, {4:1}]**.

I pass my argument accordingly:

```
class_weights = [{0: 10, 1: 1}, {0: 6, 1: 1}, {0: 3, 1: 1}, {0: 1, 1: 1}, {0: 2, 1: 1}]
forest = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1, n_estimators=200, class_weight=class_weights)
```

However, when running the code I get the following error.

```
ValueError: class_weight must be dict, 'balanced', or None, got: [{0: 10, 1: 1}, {0: 6, 1: 1}, {0: 3, 1: 1}, {0: 1, 1: 1}, {0: 2, 1: 1}]
```

The version of scikit learn used is 1.0.

What is the issue here?